# jQuery slide down navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple jQuery slide down navigation but I'm having a bit of a issue with toggle in on and off the navigation.

**I have navigation as follows.**

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>home</li>
<li class="parent">Clothing
    <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent">shoes
    <ul>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child</li>
        <li>child
                       <ul>
                          <li>child child</li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**with the following jquery**

```
var $j  =   jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {


$j('#nav').children('.parent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $j(this);
    $j('#nav').children('.parent').children('ul').stop().slideUp('slow', function(){
        $this.children('ul').stop().slideToggle('slow');        
    });
});

});
```

Now when i click the Sub navigation slides out, clicking again does nothing, and i need it to slide back up. If i click another one what I need to happen is have the expanded nav (if any) slide back up, and then the new one slide down after, but it's just not wanting to work correctly for me! It's buggy and both display at once, and sometimes don't show.

Comment: can you jsfiddle this example?  should be easy enough to add the necessary html, css, and js to get a working example.

Comment: you'd think so, but I'm working on magento doing overwrites on the standard css template with a load more css, so the html and css is too much of a mess. I tried to create it simpler on jsfiddle but it came out even worse =.=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this...

```
var $j  =   jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#nav > .parent').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $j('#nav > .parent').children().stop().slideUp('slow');
        $j(this).children().stop().slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

See this [jSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUmGz/1/)

Comment: Almost MG.  It doesn't collapse other expanded (or expanding) children before expanding the new one.

Comment: Looking good! I'd edit your answer with this new fiddle then +1 for answer.